# Grouping same data in a single dictionary while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying scrape country name, GDP and population from [this website](https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-national-debt/). I am using `Scrapy` with `Python 3.7`. The problem is I am getting all the country data in a dictionary, all the GDP data in a dictionary and all the population data in a dictionary. But I want corresponding country data, GDP and population in a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class DebtByCountriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'debt_by_countries'
    allowed_domains = ['worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-national-debt']
    start_urls = ['https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-national-debt/']

    def parse(self, response):

        # countries = response.xpath("//td/a/text()").getall()

        countries = response.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/a/text()").getall()
        GDP = response.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2]/text()").getall()
        population = response.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[3]/text()").getall()


        yield{
            "country_name": countries,
            "GDP": GDP,
            "population": population

        }
```

Here is the output of my code:

[image: Output 1]

But this is what I want (including the population):

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip`, we can create a dictionary for each country and yield from there.

```py
for country, gdp, pop in zip(countries, GDP, population):
    yield {"country_name": country, "GDP": gdp, "population": pop}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that the generator is just going to yield a single huge dictionary, where each value is the entire list `countries`, `GDP`, and `population`, respectively. To remedy this, you will want to create a dictionary for each country and yield each element per `next` call as shown above.

To test the generator, try

```py
gen = parse(response) # or self.parse(response) depending on context
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```

Each time `next` is called, the generator will yield a different dictionary corresponding to a new country.

Comment: Now I am getting all the country repetitively in each cell. But GDP and population are working.

Comment: That is odd. Are you sure you typed `yield {"country_name": country,`  instead of `yield {"country_name": countries,`?

Comment: Oh sorry! Yeah, I typed countries there. Now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped!